# Visual Studio Performance Test file upload parameter prefixes date

Tags: visual-studio-2015, performance-testing

I have a problem that hopefully has an easy solution I am overlooking... this is my first time using file upload parameters with Visual Studio performance test tools. When I first ran my web performance test, my test found the file and uploaded it as I expected. However, when I re-run the test now, I get a 500 Internal Server error in the "Details" section of the results, and I noticed that my filename includes what appears to be a timestamp prefixed to the correct name in the request. Since my filename isn't changing, this causes visual studio to fail to find my document.

I generated code for this test because I needed to reset the SSL settings manually. My document is moved to the Test Results folder because I decorated the method with it as a DeploymentItem. Visual studio did this automatically when I generated the code, which was very nice but could be the issue... Any help would be greatly appreciated! Here's the POST request I'm making:

```
WebTestRequest request11 = new WebTestRequest((this.Context["Environment"].ToString() + "/Submit/Upload"));
request11.Method = "POST";
request11.Headers.Add(new WebTestRequestHeader("Referer", (this.Context["Environment"].ToString() + "/Submit/Index/fakefolder456")));
FormPostHttpBody request11Body = new FormPostHttpBody();
request11Body.FormPostParameters.Add(new FileUploadParameter("files", "Test3.pptx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation", true));
request11Body.FormPostParameters.Add("folderId", "fakeId123");
request11Body.FormPostParameters.Add("fileNamePairs", "[{\"OriginalFileName\" : \"Test3.pptx\",\"NewFileName\" : \"Test3.pptx\"}]");
request11Body.FormPostParameters.Add("__RequestVerificationToken", this.Context["$HIDDEN1.__RequestVerificationToken"].ToString());
request11.Body = request11Body;
yield return request11;
request11 = null;
```

Comment: Which filename? There are 3 of `Test3.pptx` in the code shown. There are also `OriginalFileName` and `NewFileName`. What are the request and response when the test is run?

Comment: I have only ever converted a web test to code for debugging/diagnostic reasons. Everything else I have needed has been better done via plugins. Converting to code makes the rest of the test much much harder to manage and modify. If you really need to do a whole request via converting to C# code then I suggest using the web test's context (right click) menu command `Extract web test` then converting that one request.

Comment: Do you know if I can set the request SecurityProtocolType with a plugin? I've never used plugins before but will research... I have to add this line of code to get my performance tests working, which instructs my request to use TLS 1.2 for SSL encryption: `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Comment: Plugins are, IMHO, much easier overall than converting to a coded test. I cannot think of any reason why the `ServicePointManager... = ...` code cannot be used in a plugin.

Comment: Thanks AdrianHHH! I taught myself how to use the plugins and it works wonderfully. You're right on-- it's a far better design than generating the code

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the solution to my issue-- my File Upload Parameter had a setting "Generate Unique Name" set to "true". Visual Studio's method of making a filename unique is to take today's date and time and prepend it to your given filename. Also, you need to make sure the file you want to upload is getting transferred to your output folder. I did this by double clicking my testsettings file, checking the box "Enable deployment", then adding my file to the files to be deployed. I believe this will deploy the file for every single test though... it would be preferable to deploy the file for just my test. These links helped in my research: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/edglas/2008/08/05/how-to-upload-a-file-in-a-web-test/,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alikl/2010/04/26/file-upload-in-a-web-test-the-case-of-submitting-a-form-with-javascript/,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d094493-9b9b-4c78-bb98-f80068a643fc/is-it-possible-to-add-deployment-item-to-the-webtest-using-code?forum=vstswebtest.

For those of you who read AdrianHHH's excellent help in the comments, I learned how to write web test plugins using Ben Day's Pluralsight course "Load Testing With Visual Studio" https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/load-testing-visual-studio-2013/table-of-contents, and my plugin looks like this:

```
namespace WebTestPlugins
{
    public class SsoAuth : WebTestPlugin
    {
        public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
            {
            // Set the security protocol to TLS 1.2
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            }
    }
}
```